# Examples of two definitions equivalent in ZFC, but inequivalent in ZF set theory.

Tags: axiom-of-choice

What are two definitions of an object or class of objects, which are equivalent assuming the axiom of choice, but are inequivalent assuming only ZF set theory? I am not looking for theorems that are inequivalent, more like interesting examples of definitions.

Comment: yes for example dedekind finite sets ( doesn't have proper subset of same cardinality) correspond to sets that have finite cardinality (are in bijection with a finite cardinal) in ZFC but not in ZF

Comment: "vector space" and "free module over a field" are equivalent with choice, but aren't without

Comment: @Arthur my bad I meant the opposite

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theorems tend to translate into definitions.

As people mentioned in the comments, in $\sf ZFC$ we can prove the theorem that a set is infinite if and only if it contains a countably infinite subset. In $\sf ZF$ this isn't true, so it becomes a type of definition.

In $\sf ZFC$ a ring is Noetherian if one of the two equivalent definitions hold:

1. Every collection of ideals contains a maximal element;
2. every increasing chain of ideals is finite.

In $\sf ZF$ the equivalent fails, and they turn into two separate definitions.

This extends to *every* theorem of $\sf ZFC$ that fails in $\sf ZF$.

Comment: Wait, can you give me examples of rings in ZF which differ among those properties? Also, in ZF does 1. imply 2., or vice versa?

Comment: Yes, 1 implies 2. As for examples, Hodges has a nice paper "Six Impossible Rings" where he has an example (as far as "has an example" to a counterexample to AC can go).

Comment: If you want something that is inequivalent: (I) $X$ can be linearly ordered without a maximum element; (II) $X$ can be partitioned into infinitely many infinite sets. In ZFC those are the same, but in ZF neither one implies the other..